# BxSlider Behaviour for mobile view

Tags: bxslider

How to prevent BxSlider to jump back to the first slide in infiniteLoop condition. The default behaviour is to jump back to first slide. I want it to go to the first slide normally as other slide comes from the right.

Answer (score 0):

If you set it's mode to `'horizontal'` it works like you want to do. bxslider's default infinite loop value is `true`, so you don't have to change anymore values.

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
     mode: 'horizontal',
     auto: true,
     pause:4750,
     speed: 2000
});
```